# A completely disorderly organization or country

Tags: idioms, expressions

In everyday English speech and in casual manner how would you describe an **organization** or a **country** which is too chaotic and disorderly, in which everything is in jumbled confusion, nobody is in their rightful place, everything is higgledy-piggledy, everybody has their nose in other's business and wants to work / live in the way they want without observing laws and regulations?
In these kinds of communities / societies, enployees / pleple usualy do what they want, due to the lack of proper systematic management!

I have found the following explanation to describe such communities/societies/countries:

> - This organization / country is the **wild-wild-west**.

Does this sentence sound idiomatic to you?
If not, then please let me know how would you name or describe that situation?

Answer (score 1):

"The wild west" is one idiom for it, yes. No doubling of "wild". You could also use plain language rather than idiom and call it *anarchic* or describe it as *anarchy* (adjective vs noun, there), or *lawless*. If it's a matter of disorganisation rather than anything else, such that it is ineffectual or chaotic, you could use the colourful expression *shitshow* - that implies that someone should be making it orderly or effective, and they have failed to do so.

Comment: Thank you so much @SamBC for the informative post. Interesting! So, saying either: **"In this organization / country, everything is a "shitshow"** or **"This organization/country is wild-west."** would work probabely in this sense? Also please let me know about the case or **"Everything in this country/organization is anarchic"** too!

Comment: Also @SamBC, as I see "shitshow" is vulgar, while although what Im looking for is an informal concept in everyday speech, but it is not considered as vulgarity. Therefore I think, wild west would be the beat term. Do you agree?